# Passing parameters to [Javascript] functions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this php grid display from ms sql server.

```
         <?php while ($record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1)) { ?>
             <tr  bgcolor="#db97c6">
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?php echo $record['ProductName']; ?></td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?php echo $record['BrandName']; ?></td>  
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?php echo $record['ProductPrice']; ?></td> 
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?php echo number_format($record['ProductQty'],0); ?></td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?php echo number_format($record['TotalValue'],2); ?></td>  
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?php echo number_format($record['Discount'],2); ?></td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?php echo number_format($record['NetValue'],2); ?></td>
                <td nowrap="nowrap" align="center"><?php echo number_format($record['QtySupplied'],0); ?></td>
                <td align="center"> 
                    <a href="javascript:openForm(<?php echo $record['PurchaseOrderDetlID'];?>);"><img src="images/update.png" height="15" width="15"></a>       
                </td> 
              </tr>    
              <?php  
                }  
              ?>
```

I want to pass `PurchaseOrderDetlID` to a javascript function which will open a popup window to edit the selected record

this is the javascript function.

```
function openForm(ParamId) {    
        $MyPurchaseOrderDetlID = ParamId;
        document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display="block";
    }
```

this is the popup window

```
<div class="login-popup">
  <div class="form-popup" id="popupForm">
    <form action="ProfileSrc.php" class="form-container">
        <input type="text" id="ParamId" name="ParamId" value = "<?php echo $MyPurchaseOrderDetlID;?>" style="width:60px" >
        <br>
        <label for="QtyIn"> <strong>Qty Supplied</strong></label>
        <br><br>
        <input type="number" id="QtyIn" name="QtyIn" value=0.00 style="width:60px; text-align: right" required>
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to pass `PurchaseOrderDetlID` to the popup (edit) window

Comment: what you mean that you are not able? error? undefined? what?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through the js function parameter. The same way you change the style of the form (display = block), you can set the value of the input:

```js
function openForm(ParamId) {
    document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ParamId").value = ParamId;
}
```

Also no need to add the value in the form using PHP:

```html
<input type="text" id="ParamId" name="ParamId" value="" style="width:60px">
```

This way every time openForm gets called/triggered it will set the value of the input with the desired value.